# Need help on homework about tracert in windows

Tags: networking, command-prompt, whois, windows-networking

**This is the question**

Select three random companies, and issue the whois and traceroute (tracert in Windows) commands for each one.  Tracert is available from a command prompt.  To use whois, you will need to search for an online tool. Then write a short paragraph about each utility outlining the kinds of information available from each.  Copy & Paste screen shots for each utility and each company to back up the reported findings.

**Assuming i am a noob. I would be glad if someone would outline how to tackle this question for my homework assignment.**

Comment: The assignment seems pretty clear on how to tackle this. What part are you stuck on? Please understand Stack Overflow isn't meant to provide you with homework answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I make of this question

**Tracert**

[Read this article for information on trace routes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows)

Company 1 - BBC
Run a tracert on bbc.co.uk

```
C:\>tracert bbc.co.uk
```

Using the information from the tracert documentation will help you document your findings. Then follow the same methodology for the next two companies.

**Who is**

There is a webisite [Whois Lookup](https://www.whois.net/default.aspx)

Just put in bbc.co.uk or whatever.

The first paragraph [here](https://www.whois.net/terms.aspx) outlines the information you can get from it. Also looking up a domain will show you what information this will provide.

The information on the websites will help with:

> Then write a short paragraph about each utility outlining the kinds of information available from each.

You will then need to take screenshots.

The question is very straight forward, add a sprinkling of common sense and you have yourself an answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was a skeptical on what the term "companies" meant. thought it was a terminology i didnt cover. Proceeding to use your steps to answer my quiz. Will inform on results. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, but if you're studying programming at college and find yourself unsure about questions, your lecturer / teacher would probably be more than happy to help clear any uncertainty you might have.